# docker-compose run and exec: No container found

Tags: docker-compose

I was trying to open a second terminal un a docker with docker-compose.

First run the container with

```
docker-compose run my-centos bash
```

And when I try to open a second terminal

```
docker-compose exec my-centos bash
```

I get the message

```
ERROR:No container found for my_centos_1
```

If I search the name of running container I get

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                 COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                    PORTS                    NAMES
34a95b44f0a2        centos6   "bash"                   9 minutes ago       Up 9 minutes                                       docker_my-centos_run_1
```

why docker-compose exec search `docker_my_centos_1` and not `docker_my-centos_run_1`?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`docker-compose` is meant to run multi-container applications and is supposed to be used with `docker-compose up`. When you use `docker-compose run`, you make a special container that's not really meant for normal use.

Since docker-compose is just a wrapper around docker, you can still access this special container via the normal docker command:

`docker exec docker_my-centos_run_1 bash`

Otherwise I'd suggest start your container with `docker-compose up`. This makes it so that you can run the second bash in the way that you specified:

`docker-compose exec my-centos bash`

**Note:** I don't know if you can attach a TTY directly with `docker-compose up`, so you might need to run an extra `docker-compose exec my-centos bash` to get two TTYs.

Comment: Also, it does not appear that you really need docker-compose for what you want to achieve. Just plain `docker` is probably enough

Answer (score 4):

you need to do "docker-compose up -d"
then try ur commands

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be having trouble with the project name, because you're not telling Docker with project are you referring to.

I was facing this problem and it can be fixed adding the project name like:

```
docker-compose -p myprojectname ps
```

or

```
docker-compose -p myprojectname exec php_service composer install
```

This post explain it: https://codereviewvideos.com/blog/how-i-fixed-docker-compose-exec-error-no-container-found-for/

Answer (score 0):

Another possible reason why you might run into this error is if you have running docker compose projects such that `re.sub(r'[_-]', '', project_name_a) == project_name_b` (e.g. you were running a project without hyphens, but then decided to add them) and `docker-compose` `<=1.29.2` (likely) and at least `>=1.27.4`. E.g.:

```yaml
services:
  a:
    image: alpine:3.19
    command: sleep infinity
    init: true
```

```
$ docker-compose -p p up -d
Creating network "p_default" with the default driver
Creating p_a_1 ... done

$ docker-compose -p p- up -d
Creating p-_a_2 ... done

# do note number 2 in the output above

$ docker-compose -p p- exec a echo test
ERROR: No container found for a_1
```

That happens because [some parts](https://github.com/docker/compose/blob/1.27.4/compose/service.py#L1161) of the code support the legacy convention to remove `[_-]` from project names. More on it [here](https://gist.github.com/x-yuri/0c0bcb3437422121916c1799379133d2).

Answer (score -1):

I solved this issue by first running
sudo systemctl restart docker

Answer (score -3):

if you are using docker-compose run this command
docker-compose run  web python manage.py makemigrations